# How to configure profiles directory in main configure.zcml to create a own viewlet

Tags: plone, zcml

I am trying to create a own viewlet to change the default plone site using viewlet.I created viewlets.xml file under profiles/default directory.In the viewlets.xml file contains the code to hide the default plone logo.I registered profiles directory in main configure.zcml file like this

---

configure.zcml

```
<plone:static directory="profiles" type="theme"/> 


<include package=".profiles" />
```

But while creating instance am getting error like this
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/oomsys/brundelre3/src/bdr.theme/src/bdr/theme/profiles/configure.zcml'

---

pls anyone help me.. still i m in struck

Comment: Do you *have* a `configure.zcml` file in your `profiles` subdirectory? Only use `<include />` to include other `configure.zcml` files. Did you mean to register a generic setup profile instead?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to register the `profiles` directory. It's automatically picked up by [Generic Setup](http://developer.plone.org/components/genericsetup.html).

**EDIT**

You *do* have to register the `profiles` directory but with a ZCML stanza like this:

```
<configure
  xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope">

  <includeDependencies package="." />

  <genericsetup:registerProfile
    name="default"
    title="PACKAGE.DOTTED.NAME"
    directory="profiles/default"
    description="DESCRIPTION"
    provides="Products.GenericSetup.interfaces.EXTENSION"
    />

</configure>
```

Once you install your package it will automatically run all the xml files within `profiles/defualt`.

Comment: well, yes sorry, but not registering it as a ``<include package=".profiles" />`` as he put it on the question...

Comment: i registered profile directory in main configure.zcml file using the genericsetup:registerProfile like directory="profiles/default".. but i cant able to call my viewlet.xml file which is under profiles/default. i do not why..

Comment: @OomsysPythonteam you do not have to call it. Once you install your product viewlets.xml will be parsed and executed.